# ghc.exe: unable to load package <package_name>

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, haskell-platform, cabal-sandbox

I have recently started learning `haskell` and have never used the `cabal` package manager before. I'm currently working on a project that requires me to user the [`io-streams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams) package.

I of course already have the Haskell Platform installed on my machine. I am currently using the `x86_64-core version 8.4.3` installer.

Using a Git Bash terminal on Windows 10, I have created a `.cabal-sandbox/` folder (using the `cabal sandbox init` command), in which to house all of my downloaded packages. I have then run `cabal install io-streams` to download and install the package from the Hackage site. This has worked fine.

I have now come to writing my code. This is as follows:

```hs
module StreamFiles where

import System.IO.Streams.File

main:: IO ()
main = do 
         putStrLn "some text here"
```

However, when I come to run this, using the following steps:
1. Run the `cabal repl` command in the directory where the `.cabal-sandbox/` folder is located.
2. I then run the following in Powershell:

```bsh
Prelude> :l src/fileStreaming/streamfile.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling StreamFile       ( src\fileStreaming\streamfile.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*StreamFile> main
```

And get the following error:

```bsh
ghc.exe:  | C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\complexHaskell\.cabal-sandbox\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.4.3\network-3.0.1.0-HkosMKsQUp05NPIgp4K8kv\HSnetwork-3.0.1.0-HkosMKsQUp05NPIgp4K8kv.o: unknown symbol `if_nametoindex'
ghc.exe: unable to load package `network-3.0.1.0'
```

And I cannot work out why. Is this a package problem or is there a step that I have missed when pulling the packages down from the Hackage site?
Do I need to create a `.cabal` file using the `cabal init` command and require some dependencies for my imports in there??

Thanks in advance.
C.

Comment: Package io-streams use network as a dependency. Have you seen it installing during cabal install io-streams call? Followed your steps on Linux and didn't encounter any troubles, haskell file loads without any problems and all packages installed are visible under $HOME/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org? Can you verify if you see packages? And your missing function should be exposed by iphlpapi.dll - check if you have it.